# How to send data to from AsyncTask to `onBindViewHolder()`

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview whose `onBindViewHolder` creates a network request via `AsyncTask`. Now, when the `AsyncTask` has retrieved the response, I want to update the list item on behalf of which `onBindViewHolder` had sent the AsyncTask request. How do I do this?

I can implement a listener, but even that would not know which position to update.

I already have the new value in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can't send data directly to `onBindViewHolder`. That method is called every time when `RecyclerView` need to draw your view. You need to pass array data through contructor and access it into `onBindViewHolder`. Look [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/) for an example with `RecyclerView` and some other explanations.